# Read only /root folder

Tags: files, root, read-only

Can a user have read-only access to the `/root` folder?
For example, only in the `.bash_history` file.

Comment: If I am understanding your question correctly, and if you are running a recent version of Ubuntu, the answer is *ideally* "No". You can, of course, have an administrator change the access permissions of the `/root` directory to allow others to access it, but it's not a good idea as there are files that expect to be owned and accessible only by `root`.

Comment: You understood my question correctly. I want read-only access to the history file of the root folder. Thanks!

Comment: No, /root is root's home. A user can not even enter the directory /root. "have an administrator change the access permissions of the /root directory to allow others to access it," I consider that a serious security breach.  Users have NOTHING to do on the base system.  Only the admin and that one can do "sudo" to get into /root. And an admin can always do more than read.

Comment: I would do it like this: have the system copy the file using that user as owner to a location where that user can view files every so often (could be x-minutes but also a trigger checkgin for new lines in the file)  Altering is possible but it will be overwritten by a new copy action.

Comment: Confused by the question: On a typical multi-user Ubuntu system that is properly administered, there should normally be no `/root/.bash_history` file to view anyway, as the root login account is disabled. There seems more to this story than so far disclosed.